# Eclipse file input through CLI for Algorithms 4th edition problems

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to execute the practice problems in [Algorithms 4h edition](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/).
I imported the algs4.jar libraries and added to my Build path. While exercising the practice problems, I'm trying to give the input file as a CLI through the "Run Configurations". I'm not able to read input through this approach. What am I missing here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put the "algs4-data" folder in your project root folder. In case you have your own input files, you may want to add them too, to your project root, unless you want give the full path in the arguments.

Here is what worked for me.

[image]

[image]